# После установки wsl не запускается windows, что делать?

Tags: linux, windows, wsl

После установки wsl не запускается windows, что делать?

устанавливаю с помощью `wsl --install` в командной строке от имени андминистратора. После перезагрузки горит просто черный экран и ничего не происходит.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте включить параметр виртуализации в BIOS на вашем компьютере

Comment: проверил, он был включен, не помогает